# Is an animal's body height dependent on its environment?

Tags: development, growth, environment

Imagine the follwing situation: a newly born animal is brought into a small room. This room has no windows, but artifical light to imitate the sunlight. Furthermore, this light behaves like the sun, so that there are artificial nights and days in the room. The animal will be provided with food and water, too, so that it has enough nutrients to develop in a normal way. What will happen with the animal, when the room is so small, that it would limit the body height of the animal?
(One extreme example: an elephant, living in a normal sized room)

Would the growth of the animal be limited by some biological/biochemical mechanism? Or would the animal grow in a more or less normal way?

In summary, my question is: does the body height of an animal depent on its environment? If yes: how strong is this dependence?

Comment: The animal would grow normally to its natural height, but if limited, would continue to grow but become deformed. Do you have a specific reason for asking this?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Do you have any sources to read more about this? No special reason, I have just been curious about it. So no reason to panic: this is (of course) just a hypothetical situation!

Comment: Have you ever heard of the binding of feet in Chinese women? Hormones , and nutrition, etc.control growth, not space. Growth hormones + limited space = deformity. Sources, no. Any such experiment would be unethical, not to mention unhelpful.

Comment: @FlashTek do you think examples from anongoodnurse answers your question? If not, please explain why.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I did not really think about big experiments but rather observations about situations in which something like this has happend. Initially I thought, that the an animal in such a situation might release hormones which hamper growth hormones, so that the animal's growth will be limited.

Comment: Nature is red in tooth and claw. I can't see your situation occurring in nature. Likely the animal would die from starvation if confined to a small space unless in a lab for this particular, unethical, experiment. Even joey's outgrow their space...